# What http code for removed content?

Tags: http

Lets say I have a post at `/person/title` and the person deleted their post. But it's possible a new one will be created in the future. What code do I use? `410` could be permanent and wrong and `404` seems incorrect/overused. What code do I use

Comment: Why do you think 404 would be incorrect?

Answer (score 5):

I think 404 is the correct status code to use in that situation.  From the W3.org [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5) (emphasis added):

> The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. *No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.* The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address. This status code is commonly used when the server does not wish to reveal exactly why the request has been refused, or when no other response is applicable.